# How to turn multiple lists from one variable into one list (odoov11)?

Tags: python, list, odoo, python-3.6

I have a field:

```
 overtime_50 = fields.Char(readonly=True, default='00:00')
```

I make a list of this field and i get so many lists:

```
def _compute_sum_50(self):
    for record in self:
    x = [record.overtime_50]
    print(x)
```

Console print:

```
['00:00']
['00:00']
['00:00']
['00:00']
['00:00']
['00:00']
['00:00']
['00:00']
['00:00']
['00:00']
['00:00']
```

I need to get sometinh like this:

```
['00:00','00:00','00:00','00:00','00:00','00:00','00:00','00:00','00:00']
```

I try many ways, but i only get results like this:

```
def _compute_sum_50(self):
    for record in self:
        x = [record.overtime_50]
        print(list(chain.from_iterable(x)))
```

Console print:

```
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
```

What can i do wrong?

Comment: In every iteration, you reassign `x`, when you really want to *append* to it. Once you figure out how to do that, you may also want to look at comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def _compute_sum_50(self):
  x = [record.overtime_50for record in self] # Use List Comprehension
  print(x)
```

Edit: better solution provided by Dipen Shah